# "Authentication Statistics" graph y-axis labels are overly granular

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

Yesterday there was a spike in my app's authentication requests (thanks for that, by the way ;) which has caused my authentication graph to show a much wider range of Y values than it did previously.  The downside to this is that the graph doesn't seem to be handling this very well:

[image]

The Y-axis labels seem overly granular, and probably aren't scaling properly as the number of authentications grows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed in the most recent deploy.

The tick spacing should be saner now, and the total statistics are now downloadable as well.